# Pixels that text will give

Tags: java, string, fonts, awt

Would it be possible to get the width of a string based on its font?

So for example, if the font size is 40, and the string was "hi", could you do 2*40.

An example of this would be

```
startX = 260; startWidth = "Start".length()*getFont().getSize();
startY = getHeight()-startWidth-20; 
startHeight = getFont().getSize();
```

Comment: Look to `GlyphVector` or `FontMetrics` as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14686432/418556).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the type of font, whether it's [monospaced or proportional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Proportion). Most font now are proportional so you would not simply be able to calculate num_of_chars * n.

The gui interface you are using should give you the width of the container once it has been populated with the given text.

Comment: *"show a example"*  There are examples linked from my first comment.